# Error 404 - Not Found

Tags: apache, laravel-5, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04

Good Afternoon,

I'm elaborating a project and I've instaled php,mysql, apache2 in a virtualbox with ubuntu16.04.
I'm working locally and I've instaled laravel 5.3, I have an API running and created a new virtual host and placed the `DocumentRoot my_folder` and `ServerName name_virtual_host.` Then I went to my host files and placed a new line: `127.0.0.1 name_virtual_host`. When I place on my browser http://name_virtual_host, the laravel page appears like it is supposed, but when I type in http://name_virtual_host/api, it gives back:

Not Found

```
The requested URL /api was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at name_virtual_host Port 80
```

it used to appear JSON.
How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the `.htaccess` including the Document Rewrites?

Comment: No. How do i do that. Can you explain The process to me? @MinaAbadir